# How set the header of a Text document to APA format

Tags: libreoffice-writer

In the APA format, the header has the title of the document on the left and the page number on the right.

Is this possible in LibreOffice?

**Example**:

[image]

[More info here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/01/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your document and then from the menu bar select Insert > Header > Default Style. This will add space at the top of the page for your header and automatically place the cursor so you can start typing. See image.

   [image]
2. Start typing to enter your title.
3. Then hit tab twice to position the cursor at the end of the row. Go to Insert > Fields > Page Number to add the page number.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Running head: This is an abbreviated title that appears at the top of each page. It should not exceed 50 characters, including spaces and punctuation.

Page number: The page number should be flush right.

Here's how you can set up the header in APA format using Microsoft Word:

Open your document in Microsoft Word.
Double click at the top of the page to open the header section.
In the header section, type the words "Running head:" followed by your abbreviated title in all capital letters. Make sure it is left-aligned.
Then, add a space and type your actual title in uppercase and lowercase letters.
Insert a page number to the right of your title. You can do this by clicking on the "Insert" tab, then "Page Number," and choose the appropriate format for page numbers in APA style.
Once you've set up the header on the first page, you can typically set it to appear automatically on all subsequent pages.